# How do I use React lifecycle methods with MobX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, mobx, mobx-react

Does using just a MobX store eliminate functionality of regular stateful components? Currently, I am using componentDidUpdate to access prevState & prevProps and calling other methods based on their values. How do I access lifecycle methods like that within a MobX/React MobX store?

More specifically, here is what my my current code looks like for one of my lifecycle functions:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const currentWidth = this.state.width.window;
    const prevWidth = prevState.width.window;
    if (currentWidth !== prevWidth) {
        this.setState({...});
    }
}
```

How, using MobX/MobX React do I do effectively the same thing?

In other words, how do I (without using this.state, a constructor, and lifecycle methods) access things like prevProps and prevState in a Mobx store?

Answer (score 0):

What MobX tries to fix is the issue with sharing a 'Global' state between components, for example: a user could be logged in or logged out, and several components would need to behave differently depending on that. MobX allows you move that 'state' (logged in/out) outside the components, because it's in fact business logic, not presentation logic. Of course you would still need `this.state` and `this.setState` for those pieces of state which are very specific to a component to keep your stores clean.

What I mean is: MobX doesn't really replace anything, take it as a clean and easy way to receive new state without using `this.state`. You can (and will) still use the react lifecycle methods to react to new states (the normal lifecycle process is run when MobX detects a change in the state), and you can still use `this.state` for non-global state